# Почему в разметке не разместить знак ">" как текст?

Tags: java, android

Разметка:

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRR"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="<<" />
```

проект не собрать, пока вместо "<<" не поставить например "11". Как это обойти?

Comment: Слэшем не получилось. Может как-то не так делал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки больше и меньше являются спецсимволами и для передачи как текст их необходимо экранировать, используя так называемые escape-последовательности. Так, например, чтобы знак больше не воспринимался как спецсимвол, его необходимо записать как &_gt;(без нижнего подчеркивания), что означает "greater then", а меньше будет выглядеть как &_lt;(без нижнего подчеркивания). Подробнее можно почитать тут https://thequestion.ru/questions/145118/chto-oznachaet-and-gt

Comment: &gt; - это символ ">" , а &lt; - это символ "<"

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.